# New allocates the same memory with each iteration

Tags: c++, new-operator, heap-memory

I am trying to build a list-like heap storage of C-strings.
This is a simplified part of the program.

However, with each iteration `new` brings up the same address.

```
#include <iostream>

class listStringContainer {
public:
    listStringContainer(const char* c);//constructor
};

int main(){
    listStringContainer lsc1 ("Lorem ipsum");// calling the constructor
}

listStringContainer::listStringContainer(const char* c) {//constructor
    char * Memory_Address;

    auto time{5};
    while (--time>=0) {
            Memory_Address = new char[16];
            //the memory location is to be saved into a vector
            std::cout << "Memory_Address: "<< &Memory_Address << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Memory_Address: 0x62fed8
Memory_Address: 0x62fed8
Memory_Address: 0x62fed8
Memory_Address: 0x62fed8
Memory_Address: 0x62fed8
```

The same result on g++ and MSVS.
Why does `new` appoint the same location and how to make new appoint different addresses?

Comment: `&Memory_Address` is the *location* of `Memory_Address`, not its value. Print `static_cast<void*>(Memory_Address)`.

Comment: `&Memory_Address` != `Memory_Address`.. you print address of your variable, not result of new

Comment: Actually I need an address.

Comment: The same situation with a different type: `int x = 0; cout << &x << endl; x = 1; cout << &x << endl;` will also print the same value, and it's not 0 or 1.

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk `Memory_Address` *is* an address; the address of the newly allocated array. This is not the same thing as the address *of* `Memory_Address`. (You are familiar with the difference between *what* a thing is and *where* a thing is from everyday life. This is the same difference..)

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk Pointers are not some magical unicorns floating around. They are variables, and they have their own addresses as well. By using address-of operator on a pointer, you get *address of the pointer variable*, not *address to which pointer points to*. To print address to which pointer points to you should use `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(Memory_Address)` (cast is needed, otherwise cout will treat it as null terminated string).

Comment: Yes, this has worked for me. Now I understand that it was the address of the pointer itself, not the value of the pointer. Addresses now change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `static_cast<void*>(Memory_Address)` to get the value stored in `Memory_Address`.
Lets consider:

```
char * p;
p= new char[16];
strcpy(p, "Hello");

cout << *p << endl; // Prints 'H'
cout << &p << endl; // Prints address of p
cout << p << endl; // Prints "Hello"
cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << endl; // Prints address of p[0]
```

Consider the below same scenario but with Integer data type:

```
int * ptr;
ptr= new int[16];
ptr[0] = 10;

cout << *ptr << endl; // Prints 10
cout << &ptr << endl; // Prints ptr address
cout << ptr << endl; // Prints address of ptr[0]
```

Therefore, Integer doesn't require casting to `void*` for getting `&ptr[0]`

Comment: How do I roll back the operation, i.e., from `static_cast<void*>(p)` how do I get "Hello"?

Comment: `void * ptr = static_cast<void*>(p)`, here `ptr` is `void *` but `p` is still `char *`. If you want to print "Hello", you can use `p` or `static_cast<char*>(ptr)`